# How to continue webdriver test on pageLoadTimeout exception?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I am running my test cases on Selenium Webdriver.I have a scenario where on clicking on a particular button, page starts loading for infinite time. Since the click commands doesn't completes, I am unable to stop the page load using webdriver `sendkeys(Keys.Escape)` function.

I tried using, `driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(3L, TimeUnit.SECONDS);` to stop the page load, but it also fails the test case. Tried using try catch for the same.

What I want is that page load should stop after 3 seconds, and test should continue with the next step. How can I handle `pageLoadTimeout` so that it does not fails my test and stop page load in 3 seconds.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: this test is bad by-design in the first place.. why would the app be churning indefinitely?

Comment: yes i know actually issue is with preview on server. I have to force it to stop.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the Actions to click at the location of the element instead of using the built in IWebelement Click.

```
using OpenQA.Selenium.Interactions;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Interactions.Internal;

Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
IWebElement tagElement = driver.FindElement(By.Id(""));
builder.MoveToElement(tagElement).Click().Perform();
```

The click in the above code is a mouse simulated click.

If you do this a lot, you may want to create a ClickAt Function.

```
public void ClickAt(IWebElement tagElement)
{
    Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
    builder.MoveToElement(tagElement).Click().Perform();      
}
```

Comment: Hi chuck, As I told since driver.findElement(By.id("")).click() results in infinite load, and as the unless the page loads, driver instance will not move to next command, in ur cases builder.MoveToElement(tagElement).Click().Perform(); as (tagElement) is located via driver..

Comment: So, the issue isn't the driver waiting on the Click.  The issue is the next statement.  There is no element to which you can Send Keys.  You could try using a separate Input simulator to press the Escape key.

Comment: `Actions builder = new Actions(driver);builder.SendKeys(Keys.Escape);`

Comment: hi Chuk I tried using the Action builder at next step but it wont move to next as long as the page is not loaded